# C - Adaptive Dynamic Memory Using Linked Lists?

Tags: c, memory, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation, memory-efficient

In the case of linked lists, it would seem the most 'efficient' node is one that fits the present context, situation or need.

In generative algorithms, memory requirements are variable, so what I need is a function that would receive the amount of memory available and calculate the mathematically *most* efficient node configuration.

Now I would normally try and figure this out, but the fact is, C has been around for so long that I guarantee its already been done.

Question: What is the most efficient *known* dynamic allocation algorithm?

By 'dynamic allocation algorithm', I mean essentially a function that can take the input that is 'memory available', and use mathematical formulas to break it down into the most mathematically efficient linked-list node configuration.

--Edit--
To explain 'linked list node configuration' lets assume a generative program produces a `struct mystruct` with types `int, char, float`. Now lets say that after one cycle of the main function, the amount of available memory has changed and so has the number of mystruct objects. Lets assume the program needs to generate 2 more mystruct objects. Mathematically speaking, there should be a *most efficient* way to arrange these two objects in memory using linked-list nodes. Not too complicated. Now imagine struct types are variable and there are 100 or even 1000 of them? Making sure that all of this data is arranged to minimize memory use is insanely complicated, however,  I'm sure there is a function that represents the *best known solution* out there. What is it/where can I it?

--Edit-- Is this formula (whichever you reference) used by compilers? If no, why not?

--Edit-- If there is no such formula, explain why it is not possible?

Comment: I don't think your question is clear enough. Do you mean use a linked list to manage memory allocations? What is "linked list node configuration" refer to? Give an example.

Comment: are you looking for malloc( ) ? I guess memory management is done by the Operating system. malloc( ) internally uses OS syscalls to do this i think..

Comment: @sps No. Malloc is just a small part of linked lists. This question is much larger.

Answer (score 1):

If you think about memory allocation and fragmentation: There is no single opltimal method. The actual requeirements depend on various aspects. There are for example issues like memory protection, run-time restrictions for allocation/deallocation and - yes - fragmentation. A full garbage collector with relocation/compaction for instance does certainly provide optimal memory layout (as all blocks can be compacted to a single space without gaps), but at the cost of having to know every pointer to every block and very bad run-time behaviour.

As for compilers: they have quite a simple job for allocation. They just have to allocate static objects; the problem is dynamic memory management which is done at run-time.

Comment: I mean higher level compilers like python, or java. They obvious handle dynamic data management.

Comment: I don't see how garbage collection would be an issue if everything was done with linked lists ie. free a node when its no longer needed, add new nodes as required.

Comment: @stackoverflow909 It's never an issue functionally. The issue is in absolute performance (takes time to compact) and also variability of performance (can't in general know when garbage collection takes place).

Comment: @stackoverflow909 By definition dynamic memory exists only at runtime. So it can not be handled at compile time and hence not by the compiler. The Java compiler for example does not deal with dynamic memory allocation. That is the job of the JVM (ie, runtime).

Comment: @stackoverflow909 I agree with Alan Au. This has nothing to do with the compiler, but of the run-time environment. For Python and Java, this is a matter of the bytecode-interpreter which can also be seen as run-time environment. I recommend you dso research first before you start a fight with long-time computer engineers about things they might already have implemented more than once.

Comment: Btw. Linked lists are the most basic structures you use for such a system. More advanced systems use different data types like trees and skip-lists or others. This alone should be an indicator that there is not the single "formula" (it is actually an algorithm btw.)